# ejabberd supervisor module

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, mnesia

I need to keep a gen_mod process running as it loops every minute and does some cleanup.  However once every few days it will crash and I'll have to manually start it back up again.

I could use a basic example of implementing a supervisor into ejabberd_sup so it can keep going.  I am struggling to understand the examples that use gen_server.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you show us some code, or hints on where you are, so we can help you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an example module combining ejabberd's `gen_mod` and OTP's `gen_server`. Explanation is inlined in the code.

```
-module(cleaner).

-behaviour(gen_server).
-behaviour(gen_mod).

%% gen_mod requires these exports
-export([start/2, stop/1]).

%% these are exports for gen_server
-export([start_link/0]).
-export([init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2,
         terminate/2, code_change/3]).

-define(INTERVAL, timer:minutes(1)).

-record(state, {}).

%% ejabberd calls this function when this module is loaded
%% basically it adds gen_server defined by this module to 
%% ejabberd main supervisor
start(Host, Opts) ->
    Proc = gen_mod:get_module_proc(Host, ?MODULE),
    ChildSpec = {Proc,
                 {?MODULE, start_link, [Host, Opts]},
                 permanent,
                 1000,
                 worker,
                 [?MODULE]},
    supervisor:start_child(ejabberd_sup, ChildSpec).

%% this is called by ejabberd when module is unloaded, so it
%% does the opposite of start/2 :)
stop(Host) ->
    Proc = gen_mod:get_module_proc(Host, ?MODULE),
    supervisor:terminate_child(ejabberd_sup, Proc),
    supervisor:delete_child(ejabberd_sup, Proc).

%% it will be called by supervisor when it is time to start
%% this gen_server under control of supervisor
start_link(_Host, _Opts) ->
    gen_server:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, [], []).

%% it is an initialization function for gen_server
%% it starts a timer, which sends 'tick' message periodically to itself
init(_) ->
    timer:send_interval(?INTERVAL, self(), tick),
    {ok, #state{}}.

handle_call(_Request, _From, State) ->
    Reply = ok,
    {reply, Reply, State}.

handle_cast(_Msg, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

%% this function is called whenever gen_server receives a 'tick' message
handle_info(tick, State) ->
    State2 = do_cleanup(State),
    {noreply, State2};

handle_info(_Info, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

terminate(_Reason, _State) ->
    ok.

code_change(_OldVsn, State, _Extra) ->
    {ok, State}.


%% this function is called by handle_info/2 when tick message is received
%% so put all cleanup code here
do_cleanup(State) ->
    %% do all cleanup work here
    State.
```

[This blog post](http://spawnlink.com/articles/an-introduction-to-gen_server-erlybank/) gives a good explanation how gen_servers work. Of course make sure to re-read OTP design principles on [gen_server](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/gen_server_concepts.html) and on [supervisor](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/sup_princ.html).

Ejabberd's module developement is described [here](http://www.process-one.net/en/wiki/ejabberd_module_development/)

Comment: Hmm, looks like start_link never gets called...  any ideas?

Comment: Oh - got it...  start_link should be start_link/2 as we're passing in Host and Opts.  It works!  Now I'll try to crash it...

Comment: Good point, missed this issue when posting. Will fix it in the code

Comment: The OTP documentation state "If more than MaxR number of restarts occur in the last MaxT seconds, then the supervisor terminates all the child processes and then itself". Does our crashed module cause restarting or crashing of other modules or ejabberd itself after such binding to ejabberd_sup?