# ejabberd gen_mod development issue

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

Following this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954402/ejabberd-supervisor-module), and [this tutorial series](http://anders.conbere.org/blog/2008/08/06/building_ejabberd_modules_-_part_4_-_xmpp_bots/), I implemented mod_test module, which implements both gen_mod and gen_server behaviours. It is very stupid for now, since it does nothing more that adding itself to ejabber_sup.

My problem is that I am not sure whether the module is started by ejabberd_sup or not since I can't find it in the list provided by:

```
supervisor:which_children(ejabberd_sup).
```

Given that I have gen_mod.beam and mod_test.erl in the same directory, I compiled my code using:

```
erlc -pa ./ mod_test.erl
```

and this gives no errors. After compilation, I copied the file into ebin folder of ejabberd installation and changed ejabberd.cfg adding:

```
....
{mod_test, []},
....
```

My code is  the following:

```
-module(mod_test).

-behaviour(gen_server).
-behaviour(gen_mod).

-export([start/2, stop/1]).

-export([start_link/2]).
-export([init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2,
         terminate/2, code_change/3]).


-record(state, {}).

start(Host, Opts) ->
    Proc = gen_mod:get_module_proc(Host, ?MODULE),
    ChildSpec = {Proc,
                 {?MODULE, start_link, [Host, Opts]},
                 permanent,
                 1000,
                 worker,
                 [?MODULE]},
    supervisor:start_child(ejabberd_sup, ChildSpec).

stop(Host) ->
    Proc = gen_mod:get_module_proc(Host, ?MODULE),
    supervisor:terminate_child(ejabberd_sup, Proc),
    supervisor:delete_child(ejabberd_sup, Proc).

start_link(_Host, _Opts) ->
    gen_server:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, [], []).

init([]) ->
    {ok, #state{}}.

handle_call(_Request, _From, State) ->
    Reply = ok,
    {reply, Reply, State}.

handle_cast(_Msg, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

handle_info(_Info, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

terminate(_Reason, _State) ->
    ok.

code_change(_OldVsn, State, _Extra) ->
    {ok, State}.
```

Is something wrong in my approach? How can I be sure that the module is correctly started?

Comment: Just a thought: maybe the shell truncated the list of processes (in which case the list would end with `...`).  Can you see it if you call `rp(supervisor:which_children(ejabberd_sup))`?

Comment: no, it is not there...have you got any other ideas?

Comment: print out PID in init, so you know what to look for. You use start_link -- maybe parent is dying?

Comment: pid is not printed...but ejabberd_sup is alive so i guess mod_test is crashing...but why? can somebody test it in its ejabberd?

Comment: If you add some debug output to init(), start_link() and start() do you see them?

Comment: actually i reinstalled ejabberd and now it is working. i changed the code a bit. i will make an answer for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled ejabberd (vsn 2.1.11) and now it is working. 
I add in this answer the parts of the code which are different from the code in the questoin. Changes were done following [mod_echo.erl](http://svn.process-one.net/ejabberd/tags/ejabberd-1.1.2/src/mod_echo.erl)

```
-define(PROCNAME, ejabberd_mod_test).

start_link(Host, Opts) ->
    Proc = gen_mod:get_module_proc(Host, ?PROCNAME),
    gen_server:start_link({local, Proc}, ?MODULE, [Host, Opts], []).

start(Host, Opts) ->
    Proc = gen_mod:get_module_proc(Host, ?PROCNAME),
    ChildSpec =
    {Proc,
     {?MODULE, start_link, [Host, Opts]},
     temporary,
     1000,
     worker,
     [?MODULE]},
    supervisor:start_child(ejabberd_sup, ChildSpec).

stop(Host) ->
    Proc = gen_mod:get_module_proc(Host, ?PROCNAME),
    gen_server:call(Proc, stop),
    supervisor:terminate_child(ejabberd_sup, Proc),
    supervisor:delete_child(ejabberd_sup, Proc).
```

Hope this will help somebody else as well.